# Python: Merging two arbitrary data structures

Tags: python

I am looking to efficiently merge two (fairly arbitrary) data structures: one representing a set of defaults values and one representing overrides. Example data below. (Naively iterating over the structures works, but is very slow.) Thoughts on the best approach for handling this case?

```python
_DEFAULT   = { 'A': 1122, 'B': 1133, 'C': [ 9988, {            'E': [ { 'F': 6666,            },       ], }, ], }

_OVERRIDE1 = {            'B': 1234, 'C': [ 9876, { 'D': 2345, 'E': [ { 'F': 6789, 'G': 9876, }, 1357, ], }, ], }
_ANSWER1   = { 'A': 1122, 'B': 1234, 'C': [ 9876, { 'D': 2345, 'E': [ { 'F': 6789, 'G': 9876, }, 1357, ], }, ], }

_OVERRIDE2 = {                       'C': [ 6543, {            'E': [ {            'G': 9876, },       ], }, ], }
_ANSWER2   = { 'A': 1122, 'B': 1133, 'C': [ 6543, {            'E': [ { 'F': 6666, 'G': 9876, },       ], }, ], }

_OVERRIDE3 = {            'B': 3456, 'C': [ 1357, { 'D': 4567, 'E': [ { 'F': 6677, 'G': 9876, }, 2468, ], }, ], }
_ANSWER3   = { 'A': 1122, 'B': 3456, 'C': [ 1357, { 'D': 4567, 'E': [ { 'F': 6677, 'G': 9876, }, 2468, ], }, ], }
```

This is an example of how to run the tests:
(The dictionary update doesn't work, just an stub function.)

```python
    import itertools

    def mergeStuff( default, override ):
        # This doesn't work
        result = dict( default )
        result.update( override )
        return result

    def main():
        for override, answer in itertools.izip( _OVERRIDES, _ANSWERS ):
           result = mergeStuff(_DEFAULT, override)
           print('ANSWER:   %s'   % (answer) )
           print('RESULT:   %s\n' % (result) )
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: I think _ANSWER is the expected result of merging _DEFAULT and _OVERRIDE

Comment: You could show your "naively iterating" code, especially as you mention it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that by "iterating", you'll need a recursive routine like this:

```
def merge(a, b):
    if isinstance(a, dict) and isinstance(b, dict):
        d = dict(a)
        d.update({k: merge(a.get(k, None), b[k]) for k in b})
        return d

    if isinstance(a, list) and isinstance(b, list):
        return [merge(x, y) for x, y in itertools.izip_longest(a, b)]

    return a if b is None else b
```

Answer (score 3):

> If you want your code to be fast, don't copy like crazy

You don't really need to **merge** two dicts. You can just chain them.

**A ChainMap class is provided for quickly linking a number of mappings so they can be treated as a single unit. It is often much faster than creating a new dictionary and running multiple update() calls.**

```
class ChainMap(UserDict.DictMixin):
"""Combine multiple mappings for sequential lookup"""

    def __init__(self, *maps):
        self._maps = maps

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        for mapping in self._maps:
            try:
                return mapping[key]
            except KeyError:
                pass
        raise KeyError(key)

def main():
    for override, answer in itertools.izip( _OVERRIDES, _ANSWERS ):
       result = ChainMap(override, _DEFAULT)
```

- http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections#chainmap-objects
- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/305268/

Comment: What's the problem with *nested* dicts?

Comment: Upvoted for yet another builtin I didn't know about. But I doubt this works with nested dicts - assume `d={"a":{"x":1}}` and `o={"a":{"y":2}}`, a ChainMap of `d` and `o` would return either `{"x":1}` _or_ `{"y":2}` for key `"a"`, but not `{x:1, y:2}`.

Comment: @l4mpi: You're right. This is a cons of ChainMap: it returns the first valid mapping in the maps sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If you know one structure is always a subset of the other, then just iterate the superset and in O(n) time you can check element by element whether it exists in the subset and if it doesn't, put it there. As far as I know there's no magical way of doing this other than checking it manually element by element. Which, as I said, is not bad as it can be done in with O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

[dict.update()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) is what you need. But it overrides the original dict, so make a copy of the original one if you want to keep it.